# Excel ribbon obscures row 1

Tags: microsoft-excel, ribbon

I'm using Excel 365 (aka Excel 2016 I gather).

As you see, when a ribbon is being used it is impossible to work in row 1.

[image]

Comment: Increase the row height of the first row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can happen if the ribbon is hiding itself automatically. When auto-hide is active and you activate a ribbon tab, it covers up the interface.

**Double-click a ribbon tab name to toggle auto-hide and it should fix itself.** You may need to toggle a couple of times if it's gotten stuck.

[image: GIF for example]

Comment: I'm hoping that's the definitive solution, thanks, not yet sure. Somehow I managed to get row 1 displayed and  problem hasn't recurred.

Getting freezing behaviour and wondering if connected. Seems to be when or after formatting cells.

Tried using ProcMon (with a filter to show only EXCEL.EXE processes) but it was virtually meaningless to me:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4019461/Excel365-Freezes.jpg


-- 
Terry, East Grinstead, UK

Answer (score 0):

Had the following reply from the developer:

*Yes, that is "by design". The problem is, that when I arrange the icons the old fashion way (horizontal alignment), it is not possible for office to shrink the ribbon under a minimum with. (Because it's only one group).

Me too, I don't like this behavior, but no solution exist. 
Greetings from Zurich
Marcel Derflinger*